# GraphicsPath.AddArc() C# not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, graphicspath

I am trying to create a **GraphicsPath** object using some coordinates from a DXF file. I catch the coordinates in the following order and values as seen below:

```
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: 10 |Y1: 81 |X2: 10 |Y2: 105
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: 5 |Y: 105 |RAD: 5 |SA: 0 |EA: 90
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: 5 |Y1: 110 |X2: -5 |Y2: 110
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: -5 |Y: 105 |RAD: 5 |SA: 90 |EA: 180
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: -10 |Y1: 105 |X2: -10 |Y2: 81
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: -11 |Y: 81 |RAD: 1 |SA: 270 |EA: 0
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: -11 |Y1: 80 |X2: -20 |Y2: 80
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: -20 |Y: 75 |RAD: 5 |SA: 90 |EA: 180
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: -25 |Y1: 75 |X2: -25 |Y2: 5
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: -20 |Y: 5 |RAD: 5 |SA: 180 |EA: 270
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: -20 |Y1: 0 |X2: 20 |Y2: 0
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: 20 |Y: 5 |RAD: 5 |SA: 270 |EA: 0
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: 25 |Y1: 5 |X2: 25 |Y2: 75
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: 20 |Y: 75 |RAD: 5 |SA: 0 |EA: 90
LINE found...
LINE -> |X1: 20 |Y1: 80 |X2: 11 |Y2: 80
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: 11 |Y: 81 |RAD: 1 |SA: 180 |EA: 270
```

The code I use to insert each of the lines and the arches inside the **GraphicsPath myPath** object is the following:

For the lines:

```
myPath.AddLine(
    X1,
    (Y1 * inversion),
    X2,
    (Y2 * inversion));
```

For Archs:

```
myPath.AddArc(
    (X - RAD),
    (Y * inversion) - RAD,
    RAD * 2,
    RAD * 2,
    360 - EA,
    (CalcMax(SA, EA) - CalcMin(SA, EA)));
```

The result is the following GraphicPath:(on the left the result, on the right the expected.)

[image]

The issue here is, the Arches are being ignored from the Path, even when, as we can see above, the coordinates match, and they are being added in the correct order.

Does anyone know what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Do you expect us to guess what your coordinate list should look like? Please edit your question to include an image of the desired result, and resize-down your current image, so we can visually see the difference.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I've edited the drawing so you can see the result and the expected.(I thought that it was clear in the explanation I gave, I am sorry for being a novice.)
Regarding the coordinates, they are in the beginning of the topic, one by one, and as I mention, that is the order I insert them in the GraphicsPath. Please tell me what you need further Thanks

Comment: That's better. From what I see in the pictures, your arcs are added but also a straight line is added between the start and end of the arcs. Is that correct? Can you show some more code?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I was working with the exact same coordinates with Graphics, making much more complex drawings than the one above and it was working perfect. 
I have changed to GraphicsPath, because my shapes are like this: https://ibb.co/fpbJz6 and I want to fill it like this example in the link. 
The difference between Graphics and GraphicsPath, is that the GraphicsPath connects all the points in sequence, and always closes a "Path".
For some reason the points of my arches are not being connected with the previous and next lines, the arch is drawn but ignored from the path.

Comment: So, the arches seem to be ignored, and because of that, GraphicsPath is connecting the last point of one line to the first point of the next line. I don't know why the arches are not being considered by the GraphicsPath, since the points match perfectly.

Comment: The first arc seems to start 5 pixels away from where the first line ends, at least in the coordinates above: `LINE -> |X1: 10 |Y1: 81 |X2: 10 |Y2: 105
ARC found...
ARC -> |X: 5 |Y: 105 |RAD: 5 |SA: 0 |EA: 90`

Comment: @ZoharPeled if you make Xline = Xcenterpoint + Radius, you get the value!

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, as mentioned before, these exact code and coordinates with more complex drawings was working with Graphics. The issue here is with GraphicsPath... I need someone experienced with GraphicsPath to help me out with this topic... :|

Comment: Can you show the code that draws the image above.  A note in the Graphics Path docs says:  _If there are previous lines or curves in the figure, a line is added to connect the endpoint of the previous segment to the beginning of the arc._  I can't help but think the order of drawing is the culprit here.   The `Graphics` class does not automatically connect the endpoints as far as I can tell.

Comment: In addition to Chris Dunaways previous comment: Is it possible that the Arc is drawn in the wrong direction? Try drawing from your current endpoint of the arc with a reverse sweep angle...

Comment: @ThomasVoß I do believe you might be right. Anyway, I am not working in that project anymore, so I will not be responsible to fix that.
Anyway, thanks for your feedback.